# Error: “We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files”

Tags: partitioning, installation, windows-8.1

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 from a USB 3.0 on my Samsung Notebook. Everything is wiped clean and the BIOS settings are default. I have now just moved the boot order to boot first from USB HDD and have manually made a 100GB partition with DISKPART.  When I refresh the Windows 8 installer it shows this newly created partition yet displays this error message:

```
“We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files”
```

I have tried virtually all the fixes that I've been able to come across to no avail. I have a feeling it is something to do with the GPT tables but I'm not familiar with those.

I would appreciated a solution very much and will watch this closely.

Comment: So what does it say in the **Setup log files**?

Comment: How can I check setup log files?

Comment: log is at: %WINDIR%\Panther\setuperr.log

Comment: I had the same problem but none of these solutions worked for me. I posted my solution in another thread because OP there was more thorough in what he tried before posting, covering all things I tried before finally solving my issue: http://superuser.com/questions/945600/windows-installation-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one/1063268