# Windows installation: Couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one

Tags: windows-8.1, formatting, windows-installation

I was trying to get a clean Windows installation on my hard drive, but am running into some issues.
I get to the part where I need to select which hard drive I want to install Windows on. 
I have 2 harddrives, but both give this error:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files.

Extra info:

- Trying to install Windows 8.1
- The computer had Windows 8.1 installed before that too
- I'm installing through an USB drive with MBR partition scheme
- [Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiLbt.jpg)
- My BIOS settings: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP4YA.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9ZOK.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veeJT.jpg)
- I'm unable to copy or upload my Setup log files (since no OS) but I seem to be getting the exact same ones as [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/179807-couldnt-find-boot-disk-error-while-installing-windows-7-using-usb-post1527454.html#post1527454)

Things I have tried:

- [Cleaning the DISKPART](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2012/03/06/error-quot-we-couldn-t-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one-for-more-information-see-the-setup-log-files-quot-when-you-try-to-install-windows-8-cp.aspx)
- Formatting the drives before attempting to install Windows
- Deleting and re-adding the drives
- Deleting and attempting to install on unallocated space
- Changing the boot order in the BIOS between Harddrive and USB
- Changing the SATA mode in the BIOS between AHCI and IDE
- Changing the EFI mode in the BIOS
- Disabling USB Legacy Boot mode and re-enabling it again
- Resetting the PC through the advanced Repair options, however this would corrupt the USB drive and result in [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofZK5.jpg)
- Plugging out one of the hard drives so there was only one to install to
- [Unplugging the USB](https://superuser.com/a/657562/257316), however it wouldn't let me continue the installation or even get to the first step without the USB.
- [Fixing the MBR](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/)
- Tried Windows 7
- Resetting the BIOS to default Factory settings

None of these solutions worked.

Comment: What boot order's have you tried ?

Comment: GPT or MBR.  This error is caused by a mismatch, often caused, by people using Legacy Boot when its not appropriate.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Tried putting USB first and also Harddisk first.

Comment: @Ramhound so what are you suggesting? Should I make my USB drive GPT format?

Comment: @PraxisAshelin, did you try press F10 on this screen to run **DISKPART** & clean the disk ?

Comment: If it helps anyone, the "setup log files" are at: `%WINDIR%\Panther` more specifically (for disk) `setuperr.log`

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/789255/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition-or-locate-an-existing-system-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my specific BIOS version simply did not allow OS installation through USB:

```
Serial ATA AHCI BIOS, Version iSrc 1.20E
Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Intel Corporation
**This version supports only Hard Disk and CDROM disks.**
Please wait. This will take few seconds.
```

This would appear for about 0,5 sec during the boot sequence.

I found an old Windows 7 CDRom and it's installing without issues now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error installing windows 2012 server R2 in a Dell R210 II. My machine didn't give me a message saying it wouldn't support USB, but I tried practically everything that the OP did to no success. I checked the log `%WINDIR%\Panther\setuperr.log` and had the message:

```
Error [0x06069e] IBS GetMachineInfo:Couldn't find boot disk on this BIOS-based computer
```

I came across a webpage that said the windows installation had problems because it was using USB3.0 and I should try an older USB. I did that too and it didn't work, but it got me in the right track. I booted a CD with `grub` and booted the USB from there, finally it worked. Here's what I did once I got GRUB loaded:

```
c # to access the command line
root (hd1,0) # hd1 is the USB stick
chainloader +1
boot
```

This fooled the windows installer, because I was no longer booting from the USB, I was booting from a CD instead, even though the installer was loaded from the USB. I hope this helps other people.

Comment: lol, apparently someone is so upset about this issue that they came here and downvoted all answers..... smh

Comment: Oh well, guess I can at least upvote them all to counteract it..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I used USB 2.0 drive which worked...
I used 3.0 before and tried everything without luck.
USB 2.0 FIXED this problem.