# We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one - Windows 11

Tags: windows, partitioning

Windows installer will create 3 volumes from unallocated space but errors on installation. iirc the partitions are EFI, wsr(?) - each a few 100mb only max, and the main data volume which takes up the rest of the space.

When I try to install Windows onto the largest volume on the drive I get an error `We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one`.

I tried following this guide https://appuals.com/fix-we-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one/ . The last time I tried I got an error about the drive having a MBR partition table.

I've used the same USB drive to install Windows 11 previously on the same machine so I'm a bit stumped as to what the problem is.

The drive had a working Windows 11 install on it until I wiped it under linux. I've recreated the partition table and zero'd out the disk but so far the issue hasn't changed.

I see there's a similar issue [Windows installation: Couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one](https://superuser.com/questions/945600/windows-installation-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one) but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Motherboard is a Gigabyte Z490 Vision-D

Setup Logs: [setuperr.log](https://pastebin.com/WHWmg2D8) [setupact.log 1/2](https://pastebin.com/9MvNLpyN) [setupact.log 2/2](https://pastebin.com/v9cG9g0p)

[image: Step 1 - Install to Unallocated Space]
Install process: beginning with unallocated space

[image: Step 2 - During installation error occurs]
Error encountered trying install to unallocated space

[image: Step 3 - Installing on the newly created volume gives an error]
Installer creates partitions but errors when trying to install to them

[image: Partitions created by Windows 11 Installer]
This is the partition map created by the windows 11 installer when beginning from unallocated space

[image]
The partition table has been recreated as GPT but the issue remains

[image]
This is the output of diskutil `list disk`

Comment: Drive 1 shouldn’t have any partitions while trying to install it

Comment: @Ramhound The initial install attempt is onto `Unallocated Space` - images 1 and 2. The Windows installer creates the partitions on Drive 1. Following this the machine is rebooted and installation is run on Drive 1 Partition 3.

Comment: @Ramhound MBR is the problem, not unallocated space vs. partitions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Which is exactly the reason I suggested the drive should have no partitions. *It's MBR despite the fact it has an EFI partition.* How that happen I have no idea, probably a result, of the unspecified actions of the author.

Comment: @Ramhound It's the result of OP's "experiments" with Linux because it has no partitioning requirements - it can be installed in UEFI mode in MBR drives thus creating the ESP and conversely in Legacy/BIOS in GPT with a manually added unformatted 1-2MB "bios_grub" partition - and now the new installers also create an ESP even when installing in old actual BIOS machines. Now, deleting partitions doesn't change the partitioning type, does it? Granted, the Windows installer should be smart enough to see that if there's no data in the drive and it needs GPT then it should automatically convert.

Comment: There's likely some tool that can be used within the Windows installer to create a new partition table as GPT as required but I'm not sure, never needed it. If there is users must know that it'll delete all data from the drive so, again, backups.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - MBR2GPT but that requires a working installation, i don't believe that tool, exists within the WINRE but I could be incorrect.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeap, as I mentioned in my answer. But isn't there something within WinPE environment, like diskpart, that can be used? Guessing here, I'm not really familiar with Windows other that occasionally installing with the default settings and whenever needed I prepare the drives with a Linux live session which is what I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - MBR2GPT if it exists within WINRE can be used, but it's requirements, are pretty strict and the author's partition layout does not make their disk eligible.  Best to scratch what they have and start over.

Comment: @Ramhound My thoughts exactly. I've read some Microsoft docs that suggest it's possible within the installer but they're clear as mud.

Comment: Even if it's possible the partition layout must match the requirements and the author's partition layout does not.

Comment: **I do not understand how anyone could’ve arrived at the conclusion you’re looking at a MBR table.** Please take another look. _Primary_ does not imply MBR. MBR2GPT is not required, because a system is not installed. // In the meantime, OP, I suggest you do what the error says and look at the setup log file. While the setup is running, you can find them in `X:\Windows\Panther`. You can access a Command Prompt using Shift+F10.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB I've added the setup logs to the question. I think the information in the logs is a bit over my head.

Comment: Hm unfortunately it’s not entirely clear what the state was when Setup started. It appears the partitions already existed? That’s not ideal. I recommend doing the following: Remove/disconnect all other drives but the one you want to install on. Delete all partitions from this drive so you only have a single “Unallocated” entry. Then install there. If that does not work, provide the logs from _that attempt_.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB . I tried to install twice during that attempt: from an emtpy drive with only unallocated space, and then again with the partitions that Windows installer created after it errored. I'll wipe the disk, remove all other disks and try the installation again.

Comment: @DanielB Installation was successful after removing the other drives. If you would like to submit an answer I will accept it as the solution. 
While I was working on the machine I noticed that my assumption - the nvme drive with the lowest ID was the one in the M2A_CPU slot - was incorrect. It's been recommended that Windows be installed on a drive in the M2A_CPU slot for the motherboard I use. I have moved the Windows drive into M2A_CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Setup log files it appears that Windows is searching all around for the EFI System Partition (ESP) but somehow doesn’t find it even though it’s there. Maybe some other drive is confusing Setup.

Earlier, Windows Setup was notorious for placing the boot partition (the ESP predecessor, if you will) on whatever drive, which often enough was not the drive the Windows system partition was installed on. This lead to confusion and boot errors when removing or replacing seemingly unrelated drives. It appears this behavior still exists.

My suggestion to ensure the installation is “self-contained” is to remove/disconnect all other drives, so only the target drive and the installation USB/DVD drive remains.

The target drive would ideally not contain any partitions or at least no existing EFI System Partition.

If no (zero) partitions are present, Windows will also automatically create a GUID Partition Table (GPT, UEFI Boot) or MBR Partition Table (Legacy Boot) as needed, no fiddling with `diskpart`, `convert gpt` or `convert mbr` required.

Once the installation is finished, you can put back the other drives and assign drive letters as usual.

Answer (score 3):

During the installation, delete the partitions whose space you wish to use
for the installation. Once that space is converted into Unallocated,
install Windows into this space.

If you have deleted multiple non-contiguous partitions, use a third-party
bootable partition editor to move the partitions on the disk so that the
Unallocated space becomes one unique space.

Comment: I've tried this a few times, and deleted all partitions on the drive and let Windows installer re-create them. It still errors on `We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one` when the main volume on the drive is selected.

Comment: Are you selecting Unallocated space, or an existing partition?

Comment: I started with unallocated space and selected that. Windows 11 installer created 3 partitions and errored. After that I selected the largest partition that Windows isntaller had created and it errorred again.

Comment: I can think of these reasons for error: (1) The unallocated space was not large enough, (2) The installation lacks a driver for the disk (very unlikely), (3) The disk has a hardware problem. For the third point, try to format the disk with slow format (not quick) for all sectors to refreshed. This will take some time for a large disk.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. The system was working until I wiped it. It's a 1TB SSD and the install worked a couple of weeks ago. I'm wondering if letting a linux partition manager touch it has left any traces that windows doesn't like.

Comment: Formatting the disk will erase everything. You may use a Linux Live USB to check the SMART attributes of the disk, if you suspect errors.

Comment: No change after formatting slowly. SMART status & BIOS test check out OK. I've added some screenshots that show what's happening. Could BIOS settings or the presence of another bootable OS on a different disk be causing a problem?

Comment: So the disk is OK. But how come that you're installing into a partition and not into Unallocated space?

Comment: I wrongly upvoted your answer. Later I've found the problem, please check my answer.

Comment: First install attempt is onto unallocated space: windows creates partitions and errors. Machine is rebooted and the next install attempt is onto the partitions created by windows installer. Images 1 to 3 in the post show what happens.

Comment: The allocated System partition is too small to be EFI. Your BIOS settings may be incorrect. Verify that you have the latest BIOS from the manufacturer, enable "fTPM" (AMD) or "IPTT" (Intel), disable Legacy, and enable UEFI. BIOS versions differ, so I cannot point to the exact settings. If you need more info, let me know the computer model, motherboard and BIOS version.

Comment: After, reformat the disk into one Unallocated space, disconnect Disk 0, leaving only Disk 1 inside the computer, then install Windows 11.

Answer (score -1):

What just solved this for me was to delete some leftover "System" partitions (from former Windows/Linux installs) on OTHER drives. Once there was only one System partition left, the one created by the installer itself, the installation started just fine, no further errors.

Answer (score -2):

I had this error with the USB I prepared using instructions in [How to Make a Windows 10 USB Using Your Mac - Build a Bootable ISO From Your Mac's Terminal](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-make-a-windows-10-usb-using-your-mac-build-a-bootable-iso-from-your-macs-terminal/). I created a USB recovery drive from another Windows machine and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).